# Get users within radius from coordinates in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, geolocation, coordinates

I have a mobile app that uses Laravel as a 'backend API' to get and manipulate data. Now I send the users coordinates to the server which updates the database that the user is at a specific location, but they have specified their radius as well that they would like to search within.

How can I make a call to the database to fetch al users with coordinates within the given radius using Laravel? I have seen a few posts on the SQL query, but I am confused on how to use that inside laravel, and would feel more comfortable if there was a 'more formal' way of doing this that a `DB::raw()` query.

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a package that is 2 years old but should be able to still be applied: 
https://github.com/douggrubba/laravel-haversine-model

Hopefully it will help.